# ¿Como puedo quitar y poner una clase con un toggle usando ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2, angular-directivas

Quiero que un `div` tenga una clase especifica cuando un `toggle` esta en `True` y que la quite cuando el `toggle` esta `False` usando **ionic 2**.

Alguna vez vi en un tutorial que usaban una condición con la directiva `ng-class` pero no recuerdo bien como hacían esto y tampoco doy con el tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si querés agregar sólo una clase al div, podes hacerlo así:

```
[class.nombreClase]="nombreVariable"
```

Para ver como funciona, podés ver **[éste plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdH9hPHQXdi9lNjctNVs?p=preview).**

En el plunker declaro la variable que va a modificar el toggle (llamada `fondoColor`):

```
@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

  public fondoColor: boolean;

  constructor() {}

}
```

Y luego la usamos en la vista para agregar o quitar la clase `blue`:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Demo</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item no-padding>
      <ion-label>Colorear</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="fondoColor"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div class="cuadrado" [class.blue]="fondoColor"></div>

</ion-content>
```

Los estilos que se están aplicando son:

```
 div.blue { background-color: blue;}
 div.cuadrado { height: 300px; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Comment: Excelente! me funciono, pero ahora me toca hacer lo mismo pero evaluando si esta en sistema operativo de iOS agregar la clase. si sabe como se hace lo pongo en otra pregunta.

Comment: Genial, me alegro que te haya servido la respuesta. Dale, si queres crea una nueva pregunta con los requisitos y trato de ver cómo se podría hacer :)

Comment: ya lo logre. :D gracias de todas forma